# Localization in ASP.Net Core (.Net 7) not working at all

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, .net-7.0

After watching a few videos and reading some blogs I find myself struggling with localization in my ASP.Net Core project, partly because it seems to be different between MVC in .Net 6 and .Net 7 (no more startup.cs file, etc.).

Anyway, I started with a new ASP.Net Core Web App in VS 2022.

Then I edit my program.cs file so it looks like this (the only things I've added should be for localization)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using System.Globalization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);

builder.Services.AddLocalization(options =>
{
    options.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
});

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("vi-VN")
    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en-US");
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRequestLocalization();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

Then I change my Index.cshtml file so it looks like this:

```
@page

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization;

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer;

@model IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<h1>@Localizer["Welcome"]</h1>
```

Next, I add a Resources folder, with two files as you can see here:

[image: folder structure]

The English resource looks like this:

[image: English resource file]

The Vietnamese resource looks like this:

[image: Vietnamese resource file]

When I run it in a browser, I see this:

[image: Welcome message]

Here we can see what might be the real problem. It is only showing the key, not the English text from the English Resource file.

So, then I change the URL to get it to switch to Vietnamese by typing:

```
http://localhost:54055/?ui-culture=vi-VN
```

However, the page just shows the Resource key text. I click on Home but nothing changes. I refresh the page in the browser but nothing changes.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: Have you checked while debugging if your resources are loading accordingly? In addition, did you had the chance to check with other locals as well?

Answer (score 0):

> However, the page just shows the Resource key text. I click on Home
> but nothing changes. I refresh the page in the browser but nothing
> changes.
>
> Any ideas what I am missing here?

Well based on your shared code and description, I have tried to play around with your code snippet, you resource file, configuration on program.cs file seems correct. But you haven't called your registered  localization service which you have defined above.

In order to do that you should call `app.UseRequestLocalization` in program.cs file down below the HTTP request pipe line conditionals or on top of `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` service. This might be causing no changes in locals.

You can do that as following:

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseRequestLocalization(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value); // You are missing this line

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Full Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Globalization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services
    .AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

builder.Services
    .AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddViewLocalization()
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    const string defaultCulture = "en-US";
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo(defaultCulture),
        new CultureInfo("es"),
        new CultureInfo("vi"),
    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultCulture);
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseRequestLocalization(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Localization}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/make-content-localizable?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and also [you can download or check the sample here.](https://github.com/kironiitdu/LocalizationProofOfConcept/blob/e52d30d0d1ebc90ce2bb377b2815648230d4dd46/Localization/Program.cs#L40)